# How to find the IP and Mac address of all devices connected to my Wifi in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can i get the list of IP address and mac address of all devices connected to my wifi in swift ?
i did lot of search to do in swift but didn't get any good working resoure .

I tried

1. [LAN-Scan](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan) but written in objective-c , and lots of error while running .
2. [LANSacanner](https://github.com/uxmstudio/LANScannerhttp://)  doesn't return mac address

Please help me to scan all device connected to my wifi .

Thanks

Comment: Since iOS 11 you can not detect the MAC address.